# Left fixed columns with table colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have used this .js files and following method.

> https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
>   https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js

```
var table = $("#ShowDetails").DataTable({
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging: false,
                    fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 1,}
                });
```

But it is not working properly , i need to know how to do table structure like this.

[image]

**high lighted should be freeze**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ishan_Mahajan/2amjn9b1/1/  hers's an example

Comment: This is about how to initialize data table , not an answer to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/137556/edit
 Make sure you have included all js libraries in this example

Comment: Add your code here too this link might expire after sometime. So it will be quite helpful for later users.