# JQuery data table with multiple header rows and fixed column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, datatables

My html table contain two header rows as below. I want to make quarter column fixed I tried an example in jquery datatable plugin but it is not working as I expexted. The table is convered to a datatable but first column is not fixed

**Example i tried** https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-stripped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="2">Quarter</th>
         <th colspan="10">ICT Sector</th>
         <th colspan="10">Shipping</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>WSO2</th>
         <th>IFS</th>
         <th>Company A</th>
         <th>Company B</th>
         <th>Company C</th>
         <th>Company D</th>
         <th>Company E</th>
         <th>Company F</th>
         <th>Company G</th>
         <th>Company H</th>
         <th>PSA</th>
         <th>Mercantile Shipping</th>
         <th>Company A</th>
         <th>Company B</th>
         <th>Company C</th>
         <th>Company D</th>
         <th>Company E</th>
         <th>Company F</th>
         <th>Company G</th>
         <th>Company H</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Quater 1</td>
         <td>100</td>
         <td>700</td>
         <td>800</td>
         <td>900</td>
         <td>1100</td>
         <td>2200</td>
         <td>7821</td>
         <td>8862</td>
         <td>6231</td>
         <td>5891</td>
         <td>100</td>
         <td>700</td>
         <td>800</td>
         <td>900</td>
         <td>1100</td>
         <td>2200</td>
         <td>7821</td>
         <td>8862</td>
         <td>6231</td>
         <td>5891</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Quater 1</td>
         <td>100</td>
         <td>700</td>
         <td>800</td>
         <td>900</td>
         <td>1100</td>
         <td>2200</td>
         <td>7821</td>
         <td>8862</td>
         <td>6231</td>
         <td>5891</td>
         <td>100</td>
         <td>700</td>
         <td>800</td>
         <td>900</td>
         <td>1100</td>
         <td>2200</td>
         <td>7821</td>
         <td>8862</td>
         <td>6231</td>
         <td>5891</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: table output]

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1

        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Same Issue Here ,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046659/left-fixed-columns-with-table-colspan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have imported everything correctly friend, i hope this helps you http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/137556/edit

Comment: you are correct i have missed one js library <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>